# why I can't send data to hyper terminal by using my mobile phone

Tags: java-me, serial-port, midp, at-command, hyperterminal

I have a china mobile phone and I connected it to my laptop by using USB cable. I have a j2me app installed on the mobile which listens to any incoming data. So when I type [AT commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT_command) in hyper terminal I get OK response. Anything else seems to be ignored by mobile like just a hello word. Why? if this is so how my j2me app is supposed to see the incoming data?

Here is an example of my hyper terminal window:

```
at

OK

hello [nothing returned and carriage returns to the begining of the line]

at hello

ERROR
```

**Update:** in my Midlet code the [DataInputStream.available()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/io/DataInputStream.html#available%28%29) or `InputStream.available` are always zero. Beside that the `DataInputStream.read(byte[])` or `InputStream.read(byte[])` always return zero which means they can't find any input. As I said the issue might be because phone is ignoring anything but [AT commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT_command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**hello**" it's not AT command or parameter for "**AT**"

Generally syntax of the AT command is:

```
AT
```

or

```
AT+<command><parms>
```

I think: Hyperterminal under Win is connected with modem in your phone, not with j2me app.

Comment: yes i'm aware of that. but the quesion still stands! if everything except AT commands are ignored how should j2me app communicate with hyper terminal?

Comment: I think: Hyperterminal under Win is connected with modem in your phone, not with j2me app. Whats the name of the port?

Comment: com4. and my modem is connected to com3. beside when i send a command atd<number> my mobile starts to dial that number. as i said the only problem is that my app can't send or receive data. when i start the app mobile asks me if i give a privilage to the app for connecting directly to PC and i press yes. but no data exchange  between app and hyper terminal happens. i tested the code, check the update on question.